# Spin of an electron (What is the meaning of spinor in terms of Hilbert space and Euclidian space?)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, spinors

In quantum mechanics, electron has a spin of 1/2 either up or down. As shown by the Stern-Gerlach experiment, the spin is quantized so it could only be either up or down. The spinor matrices, for example the spinor of x-axis spans the hilbert space so that the up and down spins could be represented with eigenvalues and eigenvectors of that space. So this gave rise to my two part questions.

1. So does this mean that the electron has spins along z as well as along x? Or is it that the spin some how align itself to whichever axis that has a magnetic field? Why do the eigenvectors differ at all if any axis could be chosen as the axis that is along the external magnetic field? Shouldn't the equation be essentially the same?
2. If the measurement of spin is along the given magnetic field, is there a constant magnetic field within an atom so that electrons have observable spin values? Or is it that when we say electron has a spin up that means the electron will move upwards when placed in an external magnetic field?
   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's look at the algebra of Spin Matrices:

$[S_i,S_j]= i\epsilon_{ijk}S_k$

This implies that no two components of spin commute or in other words, they cannot be measured simultaneously. So, to answer your first question: NO. Electrons cannot have spin along both z and x. That would be like having a definite position and definite momentum at the same time.

Now to the second part of the question. It is true that you can call any direction randomly your z direction(or x direction) and write your hamiltonian accordingly. But once you've called a direction "z" and aligned your magnetic field along that direction your hamiltonian is fixed: $H = -\frac{\mu B}{2}S_z$. Now, if you wanted to measure the spin along a perpendicular direction to that of magnetic field(say x direction), you'd have to use eigenvectors of $S_x$ matrix, that is now fixed. On the other hand you could've started by calling your original magnetic field direction "x" and wrote a hamiltonian accordingly. Then the perpendicular direction would be "y". This is the reason we have three different set of eigenvectors. Not because there is a special z direction is our space, but because once we call a particular direction z, the other directions are specified to be x and y.

You can check that if you start with arbitrary spin state, the magnetic field of the hamiltonian would force the spins to align along z and -z direction when measured.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So from my understanding the Stern-Gerlach experiment was done once with magnets above and below the electron path which would follow probability of up and down and once with magnets side by side which would follow the probability given by linear combination of eigenvectors of x-pauli spin matrix. Then what would happen if magnets were placed on all four sides of the electrons path? If we can't measure spin along both axis at once, what would the physical result of such experiment be?

Comment: Try to picture that system. You'd realise the system would look like a single magnet along a diagonal direction.. From NN side to SS side. and the spins would be aligned along that direction..